# API - filter big list with word fragment

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-web-api

I have asp.net web api application. In database I have a big list (between 100.000 and 200.000) of pairs like **id:name** and this list could be changed quite rarely. I need to implement filtering like this **/pair/filter?fragment=bla**. It should return first 25 pairs where any word in **name** starts with word fragment. I see two approachs here: 1st approach is to load data into cache (HttpRuntimeCache, redis or smth like this) to increase loading time and filter in linq. But I think there will be problems with time required for serialiazing/deserialiazing. Another approach: for instance I have a pair **22:some title here** so I need to provide separate table like this:

- **ID** | **FRAGMENT**
- 22 | some
- 22 | title
- 22 | here

with primary key on both columns and separate index on **FRAGMENT** column to make queries faster. Any offers and remarks are welcome.

**UPD**: now I've refreshed my mind. I don't want to query database because requests happen quite often. So now I see the best solution is

1. load entire list in memory
2. build [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) structure which keeps hashset of values in each node
3. in case of one text fragment - just return the hashset from trie node, in case of few fragments - find all hashsets and get their intersection

Answer (score 0):

You could try a full-text index on your current DB (if its supported) and the [CONTAINS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) keyword like so

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE CONTAINS(name, 'bla*');
```

This will look for words starting with "bla" in the entire string, and also match the string "Monkeys blabla"

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand your question but if you want to query any table you can do so since you already have the queryString. You can try this out.

```
 var res = _repository.Table.Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith("bla")).Take(25);
```

If it doesnt help. Try to to restructure your question a little bit.

Comment: I just want to be sure it will be fast enough. It will be used for autocomplete  so there can be a lot of requests to this endpoint.

Comment: You have no problem. Buh Its better you use var res = _repository.Table.Where(c => c.Name.Contains("bla")).Take(25); in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a case of premature optimization?

How many users will be hitting this service simultaneously? How many will be hitting your database simultaneously? How efficient is your query? How much data will be returned across the wire?

In most cases, you can't outsmart an efficient database for performance. Your row count is too small to create a truly heavy burden on your application's runtime performance when querying. This assumes, of course, that your query is well written and that you're properly opening, closing, and freeing resources in a timely fashion.

Caching the data in memory has its trade-offs that should be considered. It increases the memory footprint of your application, and requires you to write and maintain additional code to maintain that cache. That is by no means prohibitive, but should be considered in view of your overall architecture.

Consider these things carefully. From what I can tell, keeping this data in the database is fine. Deserialization tends to be fast (as most of the data you return is native types), and shouldn't be cost-prohibitive.

Comment: Actually we can't use db directly because there are at least two separate databases in two data centers. At the same time we need to support single list of items. Another point: it will be used for autocomplete from web site and mobile application.